# Access HDFS HADOOP using APACHE Web Server, Linux CentOS

Tags: apache-2.2, http, hadoop

If I have an apache web server as a directory how I can access to HDFS Cluster for upload and modify files, what is the configuration i want to do?

many thanks

Answer (score 1):

Apache can't access HDFS directly. You would either need to use one of the [HDFS FUSE filesystems](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/MountableHDFS) to mount HDFS so that Apache can access it with normal file access, or setup [Hoop](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2011/07/hoop-hadoop-hdfs-over-http/) or [HDFS Proxy](http://hadoop.apache.org/hdfs/docs/r0.21.0/hdfsproxy.html) (which provide an HTTP interface to HDFS) and configure Apache to proxy to that.